# Why use <VirtualHost> if you have only 1 domain name for the server ? But why can't "ServerAlias" be used w/o a <VirtualHost>

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

Okay so... i tried using

```
ServerName something.ooo
ServerAlias www.something.ooo
```

but it appears..

you can not use ServerAlias unless it is used within a

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is it like that?

What happens if the server is used only with 1 domain name and thus there is no need for "VIRTUAL" things. such as "VIRTUALHOSTS" ?

Comment: You can use the `ServerName` directive without using it inside of a `VirtualHost` directive: [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: @djthoms why can't ServerAlias be used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VirtualHost` is designed to be used with multiple sites, however, when using an alias, Apache is assuming that you have `example.com`, and are wanting `widget.example.com`.  With that said, just because it's only a `www`, does not mean that Apache doesn't see those as "separated" domains, thus needing a `VirtualHost` tag.

This is why you can use ServerName, but can't use ServerAlias without `VirtualHost`.  `WWW` and `non-www` are separated domains.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Zak, well the way internet works generally is , most domains have www. so why would apache pretend that this is not the way internet works. why should it deny www. version of the domain unless a virtualhost tag is used ?

Comment: @Zak Why should somebody have the requirement to subscribe to a "VirtualHost" environment if they only are working with 1 domain name, and as you know domains on the internet usually are expected to work with and without www.

Comment: According to Apache .. www is a separate fully quantified domain name .. Thus the need for an alias to define it ...

Comment: @Zak so this means billions of web sites on the internet are simply "pretending" that they have "1" domain name if the domain name is also working with `www.` ? is this not a form of "misrepresentation" ? if i sue them all will i have a case ?

Comment: No you wouldn't. For instance ... I have my SSL set up under `www.mydomain.com`  ..  Not `mydomain.com`.  If you were to go to `mydomain.com` your browser would give you a warning.  So I use `.htaccess` to convert my domain to www and simply define `ServerName` as `www.mydomain.com`  That's a much simpler way of doing what you are trying to do .. Read about Canonicalization ..

Comment: @Zak, if you talk about .htaccess that's like going beyond a "VirtualHost" tag because that slows things down big time. But i suppose within the realms of the Apache, creating a "VirtualHost" is pretty much like creating a ".htaccess" within the httpd.conf ( apache ). so what we have here is some sort of a concept that is not behaving properly. perhaps in the core of technology when there is a "spinable" twist, it opens up the doors for "lies" and "distortions" and so on.. as a result we end up with politicians such as "G.W.Bush" i know it got political but Apache is the core of business.

Comment: @Zak,what we have here is, billions and billions of web sites that can say " oh we only have 1 domain name" and yet, their domain name works both with and without `www.` this means according to the laws of Apache, they are `lying`.

Comment: @Zak, so they can say `oh we only have 1 domain name` and then they can say ` oh we have 2 `. it's a spin. it's a way to manipulate reality so that someone can be turned into a "prey" You become a PREDATOR when you can say 2 different things as if both of them are "FACTS"

Comment: With the speed thing in mind, you can simply drop your `htaccess directives` into you `vhost` file so that `Apache` doesn't have to "read" the `htaccess` file every time a page is loaded.  That said, whether agreeable, wrong, right or indifferent ..  That's the way it "works".